# Replacing a yaml file value using bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, yaml

I have a yaml file and want to replace a particular value in it. Note that this value can have multiple entries under different parameters however I want to replace only that particular occurrence. Here is my sample code:

```
parameters:
  - name: COUNT_1
    displayName: First Counter
    required: true    
    value: "1"
  - name: COUNT_2
    displayName: Second Counter
    required: false
    value: "1"
```

Here I want to replace `value: "1"` under **COUNT_2** only not COUNT_1 with something like `value: "2"`. I cannot use an external yml processing library of any kind, only `sed` or `awk` etc. 
I have tried the looping approach wherein I while loop through the yaml file but it gets too cluttered and confusing because I first note the line number of parameters, the try to loop starting from that line number, then compare the name value, then look up the value under that name and replace it. This does not seem to be the proper approach to me. Can anyone suggest an easier way?

Comment: Why can you not use a yaml processing library?

Comment: @glennjackman trying to minimize use of external libraries here. I know might sound silly but this is just a restriction in my system.

Comment: well, IMO, you can do it with minimal dependencies or you can do it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too bad you're restricting yourself. Here's how to do it with ruby

```
ruby -e '
    require "yaml"
    data = YAML.load File.read ARGV.shift
    data["parameters"].select {|h| h["name"] == "COUNT_2"}.each {|h| h["value"] = "2"}
    puts YAML.dump(data)
' file.yml
```

---

Using a proper YAML parser is important. For example, if your YAML looks like

```
parameters:
    - value: "1"
      name: COUNT_1
      displayName: First Counter
      required: true    
    - value: "1"
      name: COUNT_2
      displayName: Second Counter
      required: false
```

i.e. with the value appearing before the name, the awk approach will stop working as you expect.

Comment: This makes sense. I hadn't thought of this. If there is even the slightest chance that the yaml structure might change, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk '$2 == "name:" { tag = ($3 == "COUNT_2") }
tag && $1 == "value:"{$1 = "    " $1; $2 = "2"} 1' file.yaml
```

```
parameters:
  - name: COUNT_1
    displayName: First Counter
    required: true
    value: "1"
  - name: COUNT_2
    displayName: Second Counter
    required: false
    value: 2
```

Comment: Definitely saved me a lot of trouble and lines of code. Much appreciated for the prompt response. Experience shows here! This works beautifully.

Comment: If I understand this awk correctly, `awk '$2 == "name:" { tag = ($3 == "COUNT_2" ? 1 : 0) } ` checks if the name is COUNT_2 and sets the tag variable 0 or 1, then `tag && $1 == "value:"{$1 = "    " $1; $2 = "2"} 1' file.yaml` checks if tag is true and value is set

Comment: `tag = $3 == "COUNT_2"` is OK, you don't need the ternary operator.

Comment: I'll see if some tweaking to this solution works. Will play around with it.

Comment: Thanks @Glenn, yes `ternary` is not needed. Aditya: Let me know if anything is not clear and I will update answer.